# Find all occurrences of strings in a []byte slice

Tags: string, go, byte

I want to find the index of all occurrences of a string contained within a byte array.

```
func findAllOccurrences(data []byte, searches []string) map[string][]int {
    var results map[string][]int

    for _, search := range searches {
        firstMatch = bytes.Index(data, []byte(search))
        results[search] = append(results[search], firstMatch)

        // How do I find subsequent the rest of the matches?
    }

    return results
}
```

Finding the first `Index()` is simple enough, but how can I find *all* of them in an idiomatic way without consuming unnecessary memory?

Comment: I see there is also a method called `LastIndex`, you can use that, and keep reducing size of your byte array for the next iteration. It returns the index of the last match, so you'll always have an array with one less and you can keep a count or match of whatever.

Answer (score 3):

As [ishaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682176/1964690) shows, you can assign `data` to another slice variable for each search, and then reslice that variable after each match.  The assignment only copies length, capacity, and a pointer.  Reslicing only changes the length and pointer on the slice variable: it won't affect the underlying array, and it is not a new allocation.  I added this answer to clarify the memory efficiency, and to demonstrate that you can still use `bytes.Index` and you can use it as your starting point and incrementer in a traditional for loop:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func findAllOccurrences(data []byte, searches []string) map[string][]int {
    results := make(map[string][]int)
    for _, search := range searches {
        searchData := data
        term := []byte(search)
        for x, d := bytes.Index(searchData, term), 0; x > -1; x, d = bytes.Index(searchData, term), d+x+1 {
            results[search] = append(results[search], x+d)
            searchData = searchData[x+1 : len(searchData)]
        }
    }
    return results
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(findAllOccurrences([]byte(`foo foo hey foo`), []string{`foo`, `hey`, ` `}))
}
```

prints

```
map[foo:[0 4 12] hey:[8]  :[3 7 11]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so here is the solution from my comment by reading the `LastIndex` instead of first, not sure if it is efficient, but this does work, you just get indexes in an inverted order, which you can always fix at the time of reading.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    str1:= "foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoofoobar"
    arr := make([]string, 2)
    arr[0]="foo"
    arr[1]="bar"
    res:=findAllOccurrences([]byte(str1), arr)
    fmt.Println(res)
}


func findAllOccurrences(data []byte, searches []string) map[string][]int {
    results:= make(map[string][]int,0)

    for _, search := range searches {
    index := len(data)
    tmp:=data
    for true{
        match := bytes.LastIndex(tmp[0:index], []byte(search))
        if match==-1{
            break
        }else{
            index=match
            results[search]=append(results[search], match)
            }
        }
    }

    return results
}
```

Hope this helps! :)